# ClassCastException: Tuple2 cannot be cast to EasyTuple2 (EasyTuple2 extends Tuple2 )

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
package com.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tuple2<String, String> tuple2 = new Tuple2<>("abcd", "1234");
        /*
         * will throws exception:
         * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.Tuple2 cannot be cast to com.test.EasyTuple2
         *  at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:11)
         */
//        EasyTuple2<String> easyTuple2 = (EasyTuple2<String>) tuple2;

        // UPDATE:
        EasyTuple2<String> abcd = new EasyTuple2<>("abcd", "1234");
        EasyTuple2<String> self = abcd.getSelf("efg", "567");
        System.out.println(self._1 + "   " + self._2);
    }
}

class Tuple2<T1, T2>{
    public T1 _1;
    public T2 _2;

    public Tuple2(T1 _1, T2 _2) {
        this._1 = _1;
        this._2 = _2;
    }

    // UPDATE: ADD getSelf method
    public Tuple2<T1, T2> getSelf(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        this._1 = t1;
        this._2 = t2;
        return this;
    }
}

class EasyTuple2<T> extends Tuple2<T, T> {

    public EasyTuple2(T _1, T _2) {
        super(_1, _2);
    }

    // UPDATE: Override getSelf method
    @Override
    public EasyTuple2<T> getSelf(T t1, T t2) {
        Tuple2<T, T> tuple2 = super.getSelf(t1, t2);
        return (EasyTuple2<T>) tuple2;   // Question: why can tuple2 cast to  EasyTuple2<T> here?
    }
}
```

how can i cast `Tuple2` to EasyTuple2?

**UPDATE:**
why can `tuple2` cast to  `EasyTuple2<T>` in `EasyTuple2<T>#getSelf` method?

Comment: You can't. Because `Tuple2` is not an `EasyTuple2`. You can only cast it other way areound, because `EasyTuple2` is `Tuple2`, so `(Tuple2)EasyTuple2` will work.

Comment: You can't because it's other way round. EasyTuple is Tuple, but Tuple is not EasyTuple(as EasyTuple has some extra fields that Tuple is not aware of.).

Comment: @AmitB10 I **update** my **code**, can you check it again? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Upcasting is allowed. i.e.child class can be casted to parent class but vice versa is not allowed.

Comment: I **update** my **code**, can you check it again? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here child class is `EasyTuple2` and parent class is `Tuple2`. To cast parent class to child class you need to do like this:

```
Parent p = new Child(); 
Child c = (Child) p;
```

In the `main` method modify your code as shown:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Tuple2<String, String> tuple2 = new EasyTuple2<>("abcd", "1234"); 
 EasyTuple2<String> easyTuple2 = (EasyTuple2<String>) tuple2;
}
```

Comment: I **update** my **code**, can you check it again? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the edit, look at this:

```
class A {
    A getSelf() {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public B getSelf() {
        A a = super.getSelf();
        return (B) a;
    }
}
```

Is it more transparent now? Since you return `this`, you're clearly allowed to 'cast' it to it's own type, as being 'inside' instance of `B`, `this` is definitely and always an instance of `B`.